# Theme doesn't want to load localization files

Tags: localization, l10n, textdomain

Here is my functions.php excerpt:

```
function get_theme_text_domain()
{
    //Same behavior if I return the string as 'return 'whatever'
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    return $theme->get('TextDomain');
}

function tamtando_theme_setup()
{
    load_textdomain(get_theme_text_domain(), get_template_directory() . '/languages');

[...]

}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'tamtando_theme_setup');
```

`$theme` is an array with all theme's properties: as expected.
`$theme->get('TextDomain')` returns 'tamtando': as expected.

I've noticed that the theme wasn't translating any string when using `__('somestring', get_theme_text_domain())`.

I've then tried to see what was going on with the debugger, while executing `load_textdomain(get_theme_text_domain(), get_template_directory() . '/languages');`.

Here I've realized that `import_from_reader($reader)`, located on /wp-includes/pomo/mo.php, was returning false, because, I think, `$reader->readint32()` returns false.
I suppose, this happens because either the file can't be found, or it has some issue.

I've checked: the file appear correct and I've even recreated it a couple of times, using different tools, but the issue is still present.

This is not the first theme I'm writing and I mostly use always the same patterns, so I'm really lost on this issue.

Anyone knows a possible reason for this behavior?

Comment: Where is the code failing? What is returned for `$theme = wp_get_theme()`? What is returned for `$theme->get('TextDomain')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One error: the function is [**`load_theme_textdomain()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain), not [`load_textdomain()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_textdomain). The former is used for Themes to define/load a textdomain; the latter is for *core*, I believe. (Plugins have an analogous function, [`load_plugin_textdomain()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain).)

Try using:

```
load_theme_textdomain( get_theme_text_domain(), get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

Comment: You're right! Now it works as expected.
I should have mistyped it. This is this sort of errors that only different eyes can see :)
Thanks!